# RememberMe Spring Security: success handler is called multiple times

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, authentication

I am running a Spring application over Tomcat7. I implemented a remember me service in Spring with the following bean in security.xml:

```
<remember-me key="SOMEKEY" user-service-ref="defaultUserService"
             authentication-success-handler-ref="rememberMeAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

My Success controller looks like this:

```
@Service
public class RememberMeAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RememberMeAuthenticationSuccessHandler.class);

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        User authenticatedUser = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();

        if (authenticatedUser != null) {
            logger.info("Successfully auto-logged in user: " + authenticatedUser.getUsername());
            authenticatedUser.setLastLogin(new Date());
            userService.save(authenticatedUser);
        } else {
            logger.error("Auto-logged in user is empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the callback is run multiple times so that I will have four access to the database.

logs look like this:

```
2015.07.29 18:13:28 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO  Successfully auto-logged in user: t50@t.it
2015.07.29 18:13:28 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO  Successfully auto-logged in user: t50@t.it
2015.07.29 18:13:28 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  Successfully auto-logged in user: t50@t.it
2015.07.29 18:13:28 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  Successfully auto-logged in user: t50@t.it
```

I think there is a registered callback per thread. I supposed this is related to the fact that it is a Service type, however I need it in order to Autowire the userRepository

Is there a way to fix this gracefully?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not normal, could you just log more information about the request and check your client code again?

I'm pretty sure it's a consequence of multiple client calls

Comment: Yea you hit the spot. I see after logging each requests that there are 4 requests. Those request come, however, from the same page. We work with asynchronous data and there are several Ajax requests in that page.

Still I cannot see a why to solve the issue, any suggestions?